# Is there a way to import a R variable into a linux script?

Tags: r, variables, slurm

I have a Rscript which generates several variables. I would like to import one of these variables into a bash loop? Is it possible?

My variable is `variable` and I want to import it like this :

```
for i in variable
do <command line>
done
```

I do not want to save `variable` into a file and reload this .

Is there a solution?

Comment: A workaround would be to write that variable in a textfile and use textfile as input in your bash script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the R script print out the content of the variable and use a construct like this:

```
VAR=$(Rscript myscript.R)
for i in $VAR
do <command line>
done
```

Comment: What if there are more than one variable in mycript.R ?

Comment: As a general rule, you cannot create variables in the environment of the parent script. You need either to use files, pipes, or, as suggested in the answer, inline evaluation.

Comment: I saved my variable into a file and I reuse this file later. Thanks